# only show meta description is one if being sent from the controller

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Not every page I have will have a meta description so I only put it in the controllers I want rendered in the view. If I do this then I still get an error saying that pageDesc isn't defined

View:

```
<% if(pageDesc !== undefined && pageDesc !== null) { %>
    <meta name="Description" content="<%= pageDesc %>" />
<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
//
      res.render("index", {
        pageTitle: "Page Title",
        pageDesc: "Meta Description",
        path: "/",
      });
//
```

I don't have an else statement because if there is no description there should be no tag.

Comment: Try `<% if(typeof pageDesc !== 'undefined') { %>`

Comment: That's it, thank you!